# Routing with Controller name and parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have hotels list, and each of hotel has his details page, I need to navigate on that pages with fallowing URLs

```
/Hotel/HotelName
```

where **Hotel** my controller and **HotelName** is parameter for his index action

```
public ActionResult Index(string hotelName)
```

In ASP.NET MVC how can I config my routing for reach this result?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this route before default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Hotels",
    url: "Hotel/{hotelName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Hotel", 
                    action = "Index", 
                    hotelName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```